# Get custom previous business day in VBA

Tags: vba, date, reporting-services, dayofweek

I want to put the yesterday business date in my report in SSRS. In my case if using `weekday` function with `today` as parameter and it returns `2` for Monday I have to reduce by two days the today date otherwise today must be reduced by one day.

I have the following code but it throws errors when render the report.

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,CInt(IIf(Weekday(today)=2,-2,-1)),FORMAT(Cdate(today),"dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

I know Iif function returns an object type so I tried to convert it to int via CInt without sucess.

Do you know how can I get the correct date with this requeriments?

> An error ocurred during local report processing. The definition of the
>   report 'name of report' is invalid. the value expression for the
>   textrun 'name of the textbox' contains an error: [BC30519] Overload
>   resolution failed because no accessible ‘DateAdd’ can be called
>   without a narrowing conversion.

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error is.

Comment: Try to remove **FORMAT** and leave only **Today**. Let me know what happens. Format function returns string intead of date.
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,CInt(IIf(Weekday(today)=2,-2,-1)),today)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I 've added error message thrown when rendering report

Comment: alejandrozuleta did you do what @MaciejLos suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Format function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns string, not date, so you need to remove **format** function from your statement:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,CInt(IIf(Weekday(today)=2,-2,-1)),today)
```

Of course, you can format result as you wish:

```
=Format(your_statement_here, "format_you_want")
```

Cheers,
Maciej